# Can I use BDD by testing low abstraction level code?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I checked [several](https://github.com/gleneivey/wontomedia/tree/master/features) ([real](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/tree/master/features) [world](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/tree/master/features)) [BDD examples](https://github.com/teambox/teambox/tree/dev/features), but all I have found are e2e tests using selenium. I was wondering, is it possible to write unit tests with BDD? If so, how should such a unit test look alike in gherkin? I have a hard time to imagine what to write into the feature and scenario description and how to use them to generate a documentation for example by the [java collection framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html).

**edit**

I have found an example here: http://jonkruger.com/blog/2010/12/13/using-cucumber-for-unit-tests-why-not/comment-page-1/

features:

```
Feature: Checkout

  Scenario Outline: Checking out individual items
    Given that I have not checked anything out
    When I check out item 
    Then the total price should be the  of that item

  Examples:
    | item | unit price |
    | "A"  | 50         |
    | "B"  | 30         |
    | "C"  | 20         |
    | "D"  | 15         |

  Scenario Outline: Checking out multiple items
    Given that I have not checked anything out
    When I check out 
    Then the total price should be the  of those items

  Examples:
    | multiple items | expected total price | notes                |
    | "AAA"          | 130                  | 3 for 130            |
    | "BB"           | 45                   | 2 for 45             |
    | "CCC"          | 60                   |                      |
    | "DDD"          | 45                   |                      |
    | "BBB"          | 75                   | (2 for 45) + 30      |
    | "BABBAA"       | 205                  | order doesn't matter |
    | ""             | 0                    |                      |

  Scenario Outline: Rounding money
    When rounding "" to the nearest penny
    Then it should round it using midpoint rounding to ""

    Examples:
      | amount | rounded amount |
      | 1      | 1              |
      | 1.225  | 1.23           |
      | 1.2251 | 1.23           |
      | 1.2249 | 1.22           |
      | 1.22   | 1.22           |
```

step definitions (ruby):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Given that I have not checked anything out" do
  before :each do
    @check_out = CheckOut.new
  end

  [["A", 50], ["B", 30], ["C", 20], ["D", 15]].each do |item, unit_price|
  describe "When I check out an invididual item" do
    it "The total price should be the unit price of that item" do
      @check_out.scan(item)
      @check_out.total.should == unit_price
    end
  end
end

  [["AAA", 130], # 3 for 130
    ["BB", 45],  # 2 for 45
    ["CCC", 60],
    ["DDD", 45],
    ["BBB", 75], # (2 for 45) + 30
    ["BABBAA", 205], # order doesn't matter
    ["", 0]].each do |items, expected_total_price|
    describe "When I check out multiple items" do
      it "The total price should be the expected total price of those items" do
        individual_items = items.split(//)
        individual_items.each { |item| @check_out.scan(item) }
        @check_out.total.should == expected_total_price
      end
    end
  end
end

class RoundingTester
  include Rounding
end

[[1, 1],
  [1.225, 1.23],
  [1.2251, 1.23],
  [1.2249, 1.22],
  [1.22, 1.22]].each do |amount, rounded_amount|
  describe "When rounding an amount of money to the nearest penny" do
    it "Should round the amount using midpoint rounding" do
      RoundingTester.new.round_money(amount).should == rounded_amount
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know a way of generating documentation based on this. It is not hopeless, e.g. it is easy to map the `Feature: Checkout` to the `Checkout` class. Maybe something similar can be done on the method level. Another possible solution to write helpers specific to this task.

Comment: which language ?  java ?

Comment: @maboiteaspam I think the language does not really matter here, all I want to know is how to map the features described on gherkin to the classes/interfaces and methods an API has on any oo language. I guess the feature and scenario descriptions should contain that info, but I think interface, class and method names are implementation details, so the gherkin code should not contain them, they should be only in the step definitions. Maybe I am wrong about this, that's why I am interested in a real world example.

Comment: In fact i wnted to sugggest you to check about mocha framework as it provide both interface and output documentation quiet easily. forogt the link sorry, it s here http://mochajs.org/

Comment: @maboiteaspam I don't understand how it is related to the topic, it is a javascript unit testing framework, I know it, I prefer jasmine. But they don't fully support BDD, they have only BDD like assertions and that's all. Cucumber has feature and step files, while these testing frameworks have only a single spec file with mixed content. Btw. I am not looking for a testing framework, I am looking for an example usage of gherking by testing a low abstraction level code.

Comment: The example you shown before are much like what you do in mocha, except they use additionnal description to implement human readable test suites (much like behat for php). Then you asked about documentation generation, mocha can do. If you are doing unit testing then, my understanding is that you ll need code coverage, not human readable tests... anyway, i surely did not get your concerns / q.

Comment: @maboiteaspam It is not just about generating documentation. By gherkin you describe abstract terms and by the step definitions you can describe an adapter which can transform these terms into mocha code. By a framework you have classes and ainterface. So if we describe these tests in gherkin, we need to map the feature/scenario descriptions to class/methods somehow in order to generate the documentation of the classes. I am aware that there are other tools, which can do it. I am interested in how to do that properly using cucumber.

Comment: I don't why you couldn't. I would not want the overhead of cucumber on my unit tests.

Comment: @DaveMcNulla Yepp, it is for e2e and integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

A key idea here is understanding the difference between describing behaviour, and testing. In this context describing behaviour is:

- more abstract
- easy to read by a wider audience
- more focused on what you are doing and why you are doing
- less focused on 'how' you are doing something
- less exhaustive, we use examples, we don't cover everything

Testing tends to be:

- precise
- detailed
- exhaustive
- technical

When you use a BDD tool, e.g. Cucumber to write unit tests you tend to end up with tests that are

1. verbose
2. full of technical detail which only a few people can appreciate
3. very expensive to run
4. difficult to maintain

So we have different tools and different techniques for different sorts of 'testing'. You get the most bang for your buck by using the right tool for the right job.

Whilst the idea of using one tool for all your testing seems very appealing. In the end its about as sensible as using one tool to fix your car - try pumping up your tyres with a hammer!

Comment: I think the keyword is abstract here. E.g. by a password change: `"Given I am logged in as customer When I change the password Then I can login with the new password But not with the old password"`, this is very abstract, but you can use it by testing the mobile page, desktop page, rest api, business logic, or maybe even the data access just by using it with different worlds of steps. So I think if your BDD tests are full of technical details, then you are doing something wrong. (This is just my own opinion.)

Answer (score 1):

BDD describe systems as a black box. If you have any words in there related to the implementation, it's no longer BDD. Inf3rno posted an example with the correct abstraction.

I always ask myself, if the user interface was gone, would I be able to keep the same feature files? If the use cases were to be carried out over voice commands, would the steps still make sense?

Another way to think about it is, steps statements should be facts about a system, not instructions on how to manually test it.

```
good step definition
Given An account "FOO" with username <username> and password <password>


bad step definition (only applies to ui)
Given I am at the login page
And I enter <username> as the username
And I enter <password> as the password

Full example
Given An account "FOO" with username <username> and password <password>
When Creating an account with username <username> and password BAR
Then An error "Username already in use" is returned
```

Note that I could implement this last example against the user interface, against the api, but I could also implement it over voice commands ;)